# New object don't appears in the scene

Tags: mesh

Every time i add a new object, doesn't matter if it's a cube circle or whatever i can't see it just add the small dot that you can see in the picture and in the right top it appears as if was added but even if i scale it it wont show up, but it wasn't always like that, i touch something and i don't know what
[image]

Comment: im in the same layer as well

Comment: My guess would be you are zoomed way out and the new objects are really tiny from that view. After you add a new object press `.` on the numpad, this should zoom you in to see the new object. Also try `z` to go into wireframe to see them inside your character.

Comment: Could you upload your .blend file on blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com so I can check and try to help you?